# Why does "no route found" have an uncaught exception in Silex?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

My site is logging uncaught exceptions when users try routes that don't exist. The log looks like this:

```
[2013-05-30 15:47:38] myapp.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /a/made/up/url" (uncaught exception) at /home/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 92 [] []
```

Is this normal? Or is there some way that I should be catching the exception?

My error handling code looks like this:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {

    $app['monolog']->addDebug($e);

    // Some app-specific code
    $globals = $app['select_globals']();

    switch ($code) {
        case 404:
            return $app['twig']->render('404.phtml', array('globals' => $globals));
            break;
        default:
            return $app['twig']->render('error.phtml', array('globals' => $globals));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is totally normal, Symfony2 (and also Silex) logs exceptions, and a not found page is considered as an exception !

Look at this documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages

When you want to force a 404 inside your action, you are invoking explicitly NotFoundHttpException !

Comment: `$app->abort(404)` is another way.

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior outlined in that documentation for a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.  It's an uncaught exception.